# Drawing balls from a single urn (conditional probability)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've a urn with $b$ blue and $r$ red balls. I randomly draw $n$ balls from the urn sequentially and without replacement. I'm asked the probability of first ball chosen is blue given that $k$ out of $n$ balls are blue.

My attempt is as follows.

Let,

$B:$ $1^{st}$ chosen ball is blue

$B_k:$ $k$ balls out of $n$ is blue.

Then, what I'm asked is simply $$ P(B|B_k) = \frac{P(BB_k)}{P(B_k)}. $$
We have $$P(B_k) = \frac{\binom{b}{k}\cdot\binom{r}{n-k}}{\binom{b+r}{n}}$$

Also, $P(BB_k)$ is the case where the first ball is blue **and** we have $k$ blue balls out of $n$ balls. So if we fix the first ball as blue, it should be $$P(BB_k) = \frac{\binom{b-1}{k-1}\cdot\binom{r}{n-k}}{\binom{b+r}{n}}$$

Doing the division I obtain $$\frac{\binom{b-1}{k-1}}{\binom{b}{k}}$$ however the answer is $\frac{k}{n}$.

What's wrong with my reasoning? In particular, why is my calculation of $P(BB_k)$ is incorrect?

Comment: The total pool doesn't matter.  There are $k$ blue balls out of $n$...any particular order is equally probable, so $\frac kn$.

Comment: Take an extreme example:  say there are a trillion people consisting of one man and all the rest women.  You draw a sample that happens to consist of one man and one woman.  Then, as $MW$ is exactly as probable as $WM$ the conditional probability that the first draw was $W$ is $\frac 12$.

Comment: But why my calculation is incorrect?

Comment: I can't follow your calculation.  The number of combinations that have both properties $B$ and $B_k$ is $\binom {n-1}{k-1}$  and the number that satisfy $B_k$ is $\binom nk$.

Comment: lulu's comment is right, but under the further conditions that $k \le b$ and $n-k \le r$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$P(BB_k)=P(B_k\mid B)P(B)=\frac{\binom{b-1}{k-1}\binom{r}{n-k}}{\binom{b+r-1}{n-1}}\frac{b}{b+r}$$

Dividing this by: $$P(B_k)=\frac{\binom{b}{k}\binom{r}{n-k}}{\binom{b+r}{n}}$$gives $$P(B\mid B_k)=\frac{k}{n}$$

---

There is a much easyer route to  this result: there are $n$ drawn balls and $k$ of them are blue. So what is the probability that one of them (e.g. the first drawn) is blue??...

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was missing.

Comment: You are welcome. Also I advice you to wrap your head around the alternative route. Broadening your intuition is very fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

Conditioning on the first ball being blue, your calculation for $P(BB_k)$ is on the right track (although you're really discussing $P(BB_k|B)$). Take your formula for $B_k$ and replace *all* instances of $b$, $k$, and $n$ with $b-1$, $k-1$, and $n-1$. So you get

$$\frac{{{b-1}\choose {k-1}}\cdot {r\choose {n-k}}}{{b+r-1}\choose{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this approach is right or wrong.

1. We are given that k out of n balls are blue. which is a condition or ground truth.
2. We need to calculate the probability for given condition that first ball is blue.

As we have k blue balls we can choose the first blue balls in k ways and rest n-1 balls in (n-1)! ways. So favourable events are $k\cdot(n-1)!$

Now a total number of ways we can arrange n balls is n!

Prob(first ball is blue | k out of n balls are blue) = $\frac{k\cdot(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac{k}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

The sample space, denoted by S, represents all possible outcomes of the experiment. In this case, drawing m balls from the box containing n balls. Since m << n, we can treat the sampling as drawing without replacement.

Let's consider two examples of elements in the sample space and two examples of events:

1. **Examples of Elements in the Sample Space (S):**

   - Suppose we are drawing 2 balls (m = 2) from the box with n balls. The sample space would include all possible combinations of 2 balls drawn from the box. For instance:

     - {(red, red), (red, blue), (blue, red), (blue, blue)}
     - Note: The order of drawing matters in this case, as (red, blue) is different from (blue, red).
   - If we extend this to a larger value of m, the sample space would contain all possible combinations of m balls drawn from the box.
2. **Examples of Events:**

   - **Event A:** Drawing exactly one red ball.

     - Example: For m = 2, the event A would include {(red, blue), (blue, red)}.
     - Number of elements in event A = 2
   - **Event B:** Drawing all blue balls.

     - Example: For m = 2, the event B would include {(blue, blue)}.
     - Number of elements in event B = 1
3. **Total Number of Elements in the Sample Space (S):**

   - If we are drawing m balls from a box containing n balls, the total number of elements in the sample space is given by the binomial coefficient, denoted as C(n, m), which represents the number of ways to choose m items from a set of n distinct items without replacement.
   - In this case, the total number of elements in the sample space is C(n, m).
   - For example, if m = 2, the total number of elements in the sample space is C(n, 2) = n(n-1)/2.

Remember that the exact formula for the binomial coefficient is C(n, m) = n! / [m!(n-m)!], where "!" denotes the factorial.